# How to save "initctl" log-priority options?

Tags: upstart, log, logging, debug

I would like to save `init` log-prority debug options.

What is the whole process from startup event?

However, the init log-priority option to reboot and reset to the message.

What should I do?

If there is no way to modify the `upstart` source code what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'sudo initctl log-priority debug' will set the most verbose log level.  You should be able to view the logs at /var/log/syslog, or if it's a custom script the logs might be at /var/log/upstart/[script-name]

Comment: If you want to view output during the boot process (instead of just post-boot) then you'll need to pass --verbose or --debug to the kernel command-line, as detailed in the Upstart Cookbook:  http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging